# How to Increase image quality in streamlit

Tags: python, image, streamlit

I am viewing images by using streamlit without converting to RGB below is the line of code which I am using

```py
st.image("image.jpg")
```

But the problem is I need to read some numbers inside the image but the image is blurred which means that I am not able to read the numbers present in the image.

Increasing the size of the image does not work.

Comment: Do you have the image in question and a screenshot of the blurred image being displayed?

Comment: Did you try to play with the [`width` parameter](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/media/st.image)?